# Question on Order Propreties of the set R

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I have the following statement that I need to prove.

> "Show that for every real numbers x and y such that $x < y$, there exists an irrational number z such that $x < z < y$."

I am pretty sure that I need to use the fact that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational but I am not sure how to integrate that into the proof.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $n\in\mathbb N$, $n > \sqrt 2/(y-x)$. Now, let $m\in\mathbb Z$ be such that that $m-1\le\frac{nx}{\sqrt 2}< m$. Then
$$
x < \frac m n \sqrt 2 = \frac{m-1}n\sqrt 2 + \frac{\sqrt 2}{n} < x + (y-x) = y.
$$
If you replace $\sqrt 2$ by $1$, you get a proof of the fact that there is a rational number between $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score -1):

The easy reason is that the set of rationals is countable, while the whole interval is uncountable.

Comment: $\mathbb Q\cup[0,1]$ is also uncountable, but the claim is not true in that set

Comment: +1. The wording could be improved, but in fact this is the shortest proof if you know cardinaliry of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Henrik I don't get your point. Sure, it is uncountable. Thus, by szw1710's reasoning, there is an irrational in this set.

Comment: Yes, but not neccessarily between two given numers in the set.